# Paste sometimes throws an error: Pastespecial method of Range class failed

Tags: excel, vba, paste

I am trying to paste a manually copied sheet into a sheet named "Digital - Input".

I sometimes get the error

> Pastespecial method of Range class failed

This is my paste statement:

```
    Worksheets("Digital - Input").range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

This is my complete code:

```vb
Sub pasteDigitalInput()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'open the source sheet
    Call unlockAll

    'show the input sheet
    Call showerfunc("Digital - Input")

    'paste values
    'On Error GoTo feilmeld
    Worksheets("Digital - Input").range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    'Update cell references
    Call getTotals

    'Set the start of ukestrykk for digital
    showerfunc ("Kilder")
    Sheets("Kilder").Select
    range("J2").Select
    Call findAnd("Netto spend pr uke:", "Kilder", "Digital - Input", 2, 0, , , True)
    hiderfunc ("Kilder")

    'Hide sheet
    Call hiderfunc("Digital - Input")
    Sheets("Digital").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    'locks the sheet again
    Call lockAll

    Exit Sub

feilmeld:
    'hiderfunc ("Digital - Input")
    Sheets("Digital").Select
    Call lockAll
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox ("Du må kopiere planen fra excel utskriften til Adform før du bruker denne knappen. OBS! kopier planen på nytt og lås opp Digital arket før du prøver igjen.")

End Sub
```

**Edit:**
 It seems to work right after opening the two workbooks. However if I use any other macro especially the macro that cleans the input sheet, I get the error.

Clean input sheet macro:

```
Sub clearInputDigital()

Call ClearInput("Digital - Input", "Digital")

End Sub


Sub ClearInput(inputsheet As String, sourceSheet As String)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Show the sheet
showerfunc (inputsheet)

Sheets(inputsheet).Select

Cells.Select
Selection.ClearContents

'Hide the sheet
hiderfunc (inputsheet)

Sheets(sourceSheet).Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure that manually copied sheet is in the clipboard at the moment of paste? Other running programs may change the clipboard contents as well.

Comment: I have triple checked this. But a nice sanity check ;)

Comment: Are you copying across workbook? make sure you have `ThisWorkBook` is referring to the workbook you want.

Comment: Can it be that the errors happen when the user copied *before* Excel was open ? It seems to me that Excel is touchy on this point: Excel needs to be open *before copying* in order to be able to paste to it.

Comment: Thank you to both Larry and iDevlop, both workbooks have been open before copy/pasting. Yes i am copying across workbooks, and i am sure that i have selected the right workbook. It seems to work right  after opening the two workbooks. However if i use any other macro especially the macro that cleans the input sheet, i get the error. Please see updated question.

Answer (score 0):

(obviously I'm unsure what is happening in the `sub`s and `function`s that you are calling)

I don't always trust the excel VBA compiler to reference the objects that I'm coding it to reference, so I always try to fully qualify my code like the following

```
Sub pasteDigitalInput()

    Excel.Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'open the source sheet
    Call unlockAll

    'show the input sheet
    Call showerfunc("Digital - Input")

    'paste values
    'On Error GoTo feilmeld
    Excel.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Digital - Input").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=Excel.xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    'Update cell references
    Call getTotals

    'Set the start of ukestrykk for digital
    showerfunc ("Kilder")
    With Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Kilder")
        .Activate
        .Range("J2").Select
    End With
    Call findAnd("Netto spend pr uke:", "Kilder", "Digital - Input", 2, 0, , , True)
    hiderfunc ("Kilder")

    'Hide sheet
    Call hiderfunc("Digital - Input")
    Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Digital").Activate
    Excel.Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    'locks the sheet again
    Call lockAll

    Exit Sub

feilmeld:
    'hiderfunc ("Digital - Input")
    Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Digital").Activate
    Call lockAll
    Excel.Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox ("Du må kopiere planen fra excel utskriften til Adform før du bruker denne knappen. OBS! kopier planen på nytt og lås opp Digital arket før du prøver igjen.")

End Sub
```

If you're only moving values maybe you could try avoiding using the clipboard altogether with a structure more like this :

```
Sub WithoutPastespecial()

'WORKING EAXAMPLE

Dim firstRange As Excel.Range
Dim secondRange As Excel.Range

Set firstRange = Excel.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cut Sheet").Range("S4:S2000")
With Excel.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cutsheets")
    Set secondRange = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(Excel.xlUp).Offset(1)
End With

With firstRange
      Set secondRange = secondRange.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
End With
secondRange.Value = firstRange.Value


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally this error shows up when the current window(sheet) that is open is not the same one in which you are pasting something. Excel is very strict about it. When you do it manually, the sheet is selected obviously before pasting, so you will never see the error.

So before pasting into the worksheet "Digital - Input", just insert a line, above that to select the sheet that you would like to paste in and then paste. Also, I would recommend using 'Thisworkbook' if you are handling multiple files so that...you know...excel doesn't get confused which workbook you're referring to. So your code would be

```
Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Digital - Input").Select
Worksheets("Digital - Input").range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Hope this helps.